# Integration Opendaylight, OVSDB. Creation of new Manager at Reboot

Tags: networking, integration, openstack, opendaylight, openvswitch

I carry out the integration between OpenDayLight and OVS through OVSDB in order to realize a ecosystem in which OpenStack is integrated with OpenDayLight and NetVirt for the Virtualization of Tenant Network. When I set the manager in OVS. Every works: The Manager and the Controller works. When I reboot the machine, only the Controller has the label "is_connected:true". Moreover when I reboot a new Manager add in the OVS.

```
6735bd9d-3575-44fb-a1a3-6ddbf10307e9
    Manager "ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1"
    Manager "tcp:10.0.0.11:6640"
    Bridge br-int
        Controller "tcp:10.0.0.11:6653"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
        Port "tun65171854b4b"
            Interface "tun65171854b4b"
                type: vxlan
                options: {key=flow, local_ip="10.0.0.11", remote_ip="10.0.0.31"}
    ovs_version: "2.9.5"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. The service named "neutron-ovs-cleanup" create the manager every reboot. Disabling it or uninstalling openvswitch-agent (It is not needed with opendaylight ml2 driver) the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely following. Can you post the before and after output of
that ovs-vsctl show output?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The code shown is the ovs-vsctl show after the reboot of my machine. Before the reboot when I clean ovs and set manager the result is the same but there is not the row "Manager "ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1"". After the reboot the Manager does not became connected never.

Comment: still hard to follow all that's happening. Who creates that manager ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1 ? isn't that the wrong format with port coming before ip address?